# Want to Converter .png File to .vsdx File in VISIO

Tags: visio

Am tried to converter .png file to .vsdx file. but it was not opened. please provide me a solution

Comment: Please guys provide me a solution.. its very urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can insert pngs in vsdx as raster graphics
2) you can vectorize the png (eg in Inkscape), then insert as vector graphic in Visio.